# Test groups in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I need to add groups to my unit tests in Jasmine. In TestNG tests for Java we can use a @Test annotation and add groups to the unit tests. I was wondering if there is a similar functionality available for Jasmine. Any grunt plugin which provides this functionality should also be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can group and nest jasmine test in describe blocks.

```
describe('Group name', function () {

});
```